# CSS: 3 columns layout, left dynamic full width, center & right auto content width

Tags: css, multiple-columns, dynamic-columns

I need to do next thing:

```
   max-width to center     content auto width    content auto width
<-----------------------><--------------------><-------------------->
          left                  middle                right
```

SO the middle/center column and right column are going to have content inside and are going to width grow automatically. But the left one, I need to be as wide as it can until snaping to middle one.

What I have right now, it's middle and right, with "float: right".
And left one, with "float: left".

But with this, left col its width limited.

How do I make it as wide as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, this can only be done using `display: table`. If I understood right, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/guc9V/5/) is what you want. It makes the divs act as table cells, and sets the left one to width of 100%, automatically filling any spare space.

Comment: Perfect. I know that this is going to have some browser compatibility problems, but as for the project kind it is, i'm going for bingo!

Answer (score 1):

Have them all floating left.. That way they all "lean" on the left col with the max width.

Also you will need a few width considerations or clear conditions..

[This will clear up a lot for you](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-33-fluid-fluid-fluid/)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not useful. I need automatic width. Not using % or fixed types.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vcw7Q/

done just using 50-24-24 percent...

HTML

```
<div id="divLeft">
    div left to center
</div>    
<div id="divRight1">
    div right 1
</div>    
<div id="divRight2">
    div right 2
</div>
```

CSS

```
#divLeft{
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: forestGreen;
}
#divRight1{
    width: 24%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
}
#divRight2{
    width: 24%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use a width %. It needs to be fully automatic. So middle and right grows as content grows, and left fills the remaining space. Thanks. :)